# Caching the java script by browser

Tags: javascript, caching, browser

I'm wandering how does browser caches the javascript files.
I have utility.js and I use it on multiple pages. 
I know that when I go to www.some_host/page1.html the utility.js is cached for that request.
What happens if I go to different page  www.some_host/page2.html, utility.js is requested again from server or take it from browser cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is cached based on its *own* URI. It doesn't matter what caused the browser to load it (unless you have something like `Vary: referer` in the headers, which I've never seen)

Answer (score 1):

The browser normally follows the caching rules employed for the other resources (pages, images etc...)